# Spock or Wai/Warp and HTTPS

Tags: haskell, https, haskell-wai, haskell-warp, haskell-spock

I have a Spock web site which must be available via HTTPS. How can I setup it up properly for that? I think it should be the same way as for Wai/Warp, but still there's no information which is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `runTLS` fn from `warp-tls` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-tls-3.2.3/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-WarpTLS.html).

Comment: how . .exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used Spock, but how about this?

```
spockCfg <- defaultSpockCfg () PCNoDatabase ()
app <- spockAsApp (spock spockCfg yourAppMonad)
runTLS defaultTlsSettings (tlsSettings "cert.pem" "privkey.pem") app
```

Comment: that doesn't compile

Comment: @Ramiradi What's the error message?